# When Inserting a username in register page it turns into zero (0) in phpmyadmin database

Tags: java, php, mysql, android-studio, phpmyadmin

I'm using 000webhost to my android login/register app and when entering data all columns are filled in database except username it turns into zero and it gives no error

[username turns into zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfNj5.png)

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oica.png)

Register.php

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

---

Login.php

```
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $age, $username, $password);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;  
        $response["name"] = $name;
        $response["age"] = $age;
        $response["username"] = $username;
        $response["password"] = $password;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: For your own safety I would remove the database credentials from the example PHP code immediately.  Next, assign the return value of the execute statement to a variable and only return "Success" if it's actually successful.  If not, write a logfile or send yourself an email or something....

Comment: Bear in mind that few are going to read this wall of code. You should strive to provide a [mcve] that is related to the specific question you have.

Comment: There is way, way too much code here. Please trim this down and focus on the specifics relating to the problem, not a dump of everything.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: thank you for your advice i will remove it  immediately and thanks for your help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your call to bind param, your defining the username as an integer (i)...

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
```

This should be an s to leave it as a string and the age might be the integer.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $username, $age, $password);
```

Comment: thanks alot thats was very useful for me ... thank you